# How to applybindings that have different document root

Tags: data-binding, knockout.js, document-root

Hi I have the following html:

```
<div id="div1">
   <input id="input1" data-bind="value: inputIn, valueUpdate: 'afterKeydown'" >
   // ... more stuff between
</div>

<div id="div2">
   <input id="input2" data-bind="value: inputOut">
   // .... more stuff between
</div>
```

My model is this:

```
function MyModel() {
     "use strict";
      this.inputIn = ko.observable("");
      this.inputOut = ko.computed(function() {
           return transformOutput(this.inputIn());
      }
}
```

Applying the bindings:

```
var myModel = new MyModel();
ko.applyBindings(model, document.getElementById("div2"));
ko.applyBindings(model, document.getElementById("div1"));
```

I want changes in input 1 to effect input 2. What is wrong? Is their way around this without changing the html. The element are in two different divs and I want the knockout binding to apply to be apply across cross root domain.

Comment: Why are you binding the same model to two separate elements anyway? Just bind it to a single parent (or even the root).

Comment: Doesn't binding to root slow things down. I have like 14 different group of field sets of elements. (only 2 of them will be used)

Comment: Can't say I've ever had a problem with it and I've used KO on some very large pages. Either way, it's not worth worrying about unless there actually is a performance problem and then you should profile it to identify the source. Premature optimization is the root of all evil.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem isn't with how you are binding it (although I don't think it's worth the trouble). Your problem is that `this` isn't what you think it is in the `computed` property (it's actually `window`).

Try this:

```
function MyModel() {
    var self = this;
    this.inputIn = ko.observable("");
    this.inputOut = ko.computed(function () {
        return transformOutput(self.inputIn());
    });
}
```

Here's a simple [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g4p9F/1/)

Comment: Or alternatively supply `this` as a second parameter (after the function) to `ko.computed`, which will capture its construction-time value and use it as context for the function.